# moz-transition - change text when rollover other object

Tags: css, rollover

I'm looking for a real life example on how to do something like this:

Rollover on image causes highlight of text like on this page: http://shop.parklafun.com/t-shirts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question then `-moz-transition` not changing the text color. Here is the code whhich change the color:

```
div.ProductList div.grid_6:hover > a .ProductDetails h2
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not -moz-transition , it may be that the labelis hidden on that image and it is shown on onMouseOver Event of javascript.